# Deploying multi-containers apps to ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Since Docker Compose's integration for ECS and ACI is retired in November 2023, what is the best practice algorithm to deploy a docker compose application to AWS ESC?

Is there the easy way to do it?

Deploying multi-containers apps to ECS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Terraform for prepareing ECS cluster for a few years already and it shown to be a pretty convinient way to maintain configuration as a code approach.

Applications itself usually get deployed from CI/CD of your choice using aws cli.

Let me know if need more infomration, I would be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your precious feedback. I've never used Terraform before. Of course any help is precious Now I'm trying to learn how to convert compose in .tf file properly.